# How can I read a 2d array/matrix from file in C#, which is seperated with tab keys

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to read a matrix from a txt, but it doesn't seem to work at all. How can you do it if you don't know the count of the rows and columns, so the matrix in the file can be different every time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Can you give some more detail about what should be the destination of the read txt? Some code maybe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2d Array from text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724781/2d-array-from-text-file-c-sharp)

Comment: And here comes the related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125249/splitting-text-file-into-2d-array , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096776/read-2d-matrix-from-file-to-2d-int-array-in-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595938/loading-data-into-a-2d-array-from-text-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210684/read-text-file-into-2d-double-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844276/c-sharp-text-file-to-2d-array ,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844276/c-sharp-text-file-to-2d-array ,

Comment: sorry, I've edited it with a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *Linq* in order to query file:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[][] result = File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\myMatrix.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => line
       .Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Please, note, that often *jagged* array, i.e. *array of array* (`int[][]`) is more convenient than 2d one (`int[,]`)

**Edit:** If you insist on *2D array* you can get it from jagged one:

```
   int[,] result2D = new int[
     result.Length, 
     result.Any() ? result.Max(line => line.Length) : 0];

   for (int row = 0; row < result.Length; ++row) 
     for (int col = 0; col < result[row].Length; ++col)
       result2D[row, col] = result[row][col];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You've helped a lot

Comment: I mean this is really great, but I don't want to use jagged arrays. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @moladori: if you insist on 2d array (`int[,]`) you ca  get if from jagged one: see my edit, please